# Worst case analysis of $100n + 5$ for different $n$

Tags: asymptotics

For the function $f(n) = 100n + 5$, what is the asymptotic complexity of $f(n)$ in terms of Big O notation. I guess it is $O(n)$, but how can I prove it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you need is to write the definition of Big O notion:

> f(n) = O(n) if and only if there is a `c` and an `m` such that for all n :
> 100n+5 > cn for all n > m

If you can find such `m` and `c` then you have proven `f(n) = O(n)`. `c` and `m` can be 10 and 11 (as an example).

Comment: It should be 100n + 5 < cn. For c say 101 and m = 5.

Answer (score 1):

Big-$O$ is the set of functions
$$O(f)=\{g\colon \exists C>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n > N, g(n) \leqslant Cf(n)  \}$$
So we can write $100n+5 \leqslant  105\cdot n$, taking $C=105, N=1$, and we obtain
$$100n+5 \in O(n)$$